How to escape termial at start-up?
Just upgraded to 24.04 and now at startup, I only get the terminal screen that wants to install Ubuntu Pro with some 1100 upgrades. How do I (still learning this stuff, I'm a rookie) escape the terminal and get to the main (GUI) screen?

Loss of GUI and "1100 upgrades" strongly suggest a failed release-upgrade. Make a 24.04 LiveUSB, back up your data, and then reinstall Ubuntu.

This question is similar to: Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
